# error linking with operator methods

Tags: c++, methods, linker, operators

This it's causing me a headache.

I have this error linking.

```
g++ -o  node.o pathfinding.o prueba.o libmatrix.a -lm -lz -llog4cplus
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<(Node const&, Node const&)", referenced from:
      std::less<Node>::operator()(Node const&, Node const&) constin pathfinding.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [path] Error 1
```

That in the header of the class Node, out of the class declaration:

```
// Determine f_score in priority queue
//------------------------------------------
bool operator < (const Node &a, const Node &b);

// Determine f_score in priority queue
//------------------------------------------
bool operator > (const Node &a, const Node &b);
```

And in the source file (Node.cpp), I have the methods declaration:

```
#include "node.hpp"

// Determine f_score in priority queue
//------------------------------------------
bool operator < (const Node &a, const Node &b)
{
     return a.getf() > b.getf();
}

// Determine f_score in priority queue
//------------------------------------------
bool operator > (const Node &a,  const Node &b)
{
     return a.getf() < b.getf();
}
```

Anyone knows where is the problem. I'm using g++ version 4.2.1 from OSX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" Perhaps the corresponding stuff was compiled for 32 bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your command. The `-o` option is for setting the output file. You are setting the output file to `node.o`, which is writing over your object file. Your command should be:

```
g++ -o something node.o pathfinding.o prueba.o libmatrix.a -lm -lz -llog4cplus
```

But you'll need to recompile the `node.o` object file first, since you may have overwritten it.

Comment: Thanks. i forget to declare the exaecutable name in the makefile, what a mistake. Thanks.